# Registro duplicado al momento de modificarlo

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy creando un checador de empleados para registrar su entrada y salida, estoy ocupando carbon para obtener la fecha y hora, anteriormente por normas de la escuela habia realizado la modificacion del registro mediante un procedimiento, pero es la primera ves que estoy ocupando ELOQUENT [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]para realizar dicha operación, me manda el registro a modificar y todo bien , el problema viene cuando le doy submit y se duplica el registro creando uno nuevo con la fecha de salida y no se porque, anexo el codigo de mis controlador y de mi ruta

```
public function edit(checadorEmpleado $checadorEmpleado, $id)
{
    $salida = checadorEmpleado::find($id);
    return view('checadorempleado.edit',['salida'=>$salida]);

}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\checadorEmpleado  $checadorEmpleado
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, checadorEmpleado $checadorEmpleado)
{
    $date5=carbon::now();
    $date6=$date5->Format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');

    $checadorEmpleado->id = $request['id'];
    $checadorEmpleado->empleado_id = $request['empleado_id'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_entrada= $request['hora_entrada'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_salida = $date6;
    $checadorEmpleado->save();
    return redirect('checador');
}
```

RUTA
`Route::resource('checador','ChecadorEmpleadoController');
Route::post('altacheck','ChecadorEmpleadoController@store')->name('altacheck');
Route::get('/modificachecador/{id}','ChecadorEmpleadoController@edit');
Route::POST('modificachecador','ChecadorEmpleadoController@update')->name('modificachecador') ;`

[image: Registro duplicado y pero con la modificacion]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre el error, al parecer tenia algunos errores en la funcion update, ya que estaba  como `save()` pero lo cambie por `update()`, tambien que al inicio de mis variables debi poner el metodo `find()` anexo mi codigo donde hize las correcciones:

```
public function update(Request $request, checadorEmpleado $checadorEmpleado)
{
    $date5=carbon::now();
    $date6=$date5->Format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');

    $checadorEmpleado = checadorEmpleado::find($request['id']);
    //$checadorEmpleado->id = $request['id'];
    $checadorEmpleado->empleado_id = $request['empleado_id'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_entrada= $request['hora_entrada'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_salida = $date6;
    $checadorEmpleado->update();
    return redirect('checador');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo algunas inconsistencias en el código.
En primer lugar, veamos el método `edit()` y su ruta correspondiente.
En la ruta, tienes un parámetro `{id}`, que está ok para cuando por ejemplo, quieres editar el modelo con `id => 1`, accedes a una uri así `/modificachecador/1`.

```
Route::get('/modificachecador/{id}','ChecadorEmpleadoController@edit');
```

Pero en el método edit del controlador, estás inyectando 2 parámetros, `$checadorEmpleado` e `$id`.

```
public function edit(checadorEmpleado $checadorEmpleado, $id)
{
    $salida = checadorEmpleado::find($id);
    return view('checadorempleado.edit',['salida'=>$salida]);
}
```

Esto no tiene sentido si la ruta tiene un solo parámetro, y me sorprende que te esté funcionando, pues el método solo debería ser así:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $salida = checadorEmpleado::find($id);
    return view('checadorempleado.edit',['salida'=>$salida]);
}
```

Luego veamos el método `update()`.
El problema parece estar, por un lado, en la ruta

```
Route::POST('modificachecador','ChecadorEmpleadoController@update')->name('modificachecador');
```

pues no tiene el parámetro `{id}`, pero en el método `update()` del controlador, intentas inyectar ese parámetro con `checadorEmpleado $checadorEmpleado`

```
public function update(Request $request, checadorEmpleado $checadorEmpleado)
{
    $date5=carbon::now();
    $date6=$date5->Format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');

    $checadorEmpleado->id = $request['id'];
    $checadorEmpleado->empleado_id = $request['empleado_id'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_entrada= $request['hora_entrada'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_salida = $date6;
    $checadorEmpleado->save();
    return redirect('checador');
}
```

Entonces, aunque no sé cómo estás enviando el request a esa ruta, veo por lo menos, dos posibilidades:

1. Deja la ruta como está, y toma la id del input en el request para obtener el modelo a modificar

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $date5=carbon::now();
    $date6=$date5->Format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');

    $checadorEmpleado = checadorEmpleado::find($request['id']);
    $checadorEmpleado->empleado_id = $request['empleado_id'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_entrada= $request['hora_entrada'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_salida = $date6;
    $checadorEmpleado->save();
    return redirect('checador');
}
```

2. Modifica la ruta para que tenga como parámetro la id del modelo a modificar

```php
Route::POST('modificachecador/{id}','ChecadorEmpleadoController@update')->name('modificachecador');
```

Y en el método del controlador inyéctasela como dependencia para obtener el modelo a modificar

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $date5=carbon::now();
    $date6=$date5->Format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');

    $checadorEmpleado = checadorEmpleado::find($id);
    $checadorEmpleado->empleado_id = $request['empleado_id'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_entrada= $request['hora_entrada'];
    $checadorEmpleado->hora_salida = $date6;
    $checadorEmpleado->save();
    return redirect('checador');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al recibir un formulario ya no recibirías una instancia de checadorEmpleado, además no figura como parámetro en tu archivo de rutas, haré unas adecuacions a tu código

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $data=$request->only(['empleado_id', 'hora_entrada']);
    $data['hora_salida'] = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');
    checadorEmpleado::where('id', $request->get('id'))
        ->update($data)
    return redirect('checador');
}
```